# Fine-Uploader How to capture additional params for each file while still allowing multiple files

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, fine-uploader

I have the requirement to allow a user to select a file to upload and then need to capture additional required information from the user that applies to that specific file that will be sent as params to the server when uploading.

Thus far, I have been doing this by working off of the fine-uploader onSubmit callback and displaying a modal with the inputs I need. If inputs pass validation, I store the file id and associated params, otherwise, if they close/cancel the modal I call the fine-uploader cancel api and cancel the file with the given id.

The user can do this multiple times, which queues the files into the standard fine-uploader list and then they would press "Upload" to actually start the uploads concurrently.

All of this works great, my problem is that because I have the "multiple" option enabled, the user can select or drag multiple files at the same time, but I need to present the modal to each of them **individually**. The onSubmit event is firing individually for each of the files so how can I prevent the second, third, etc, modal from opening until I either cancel or save the previous one?

For the record I am actually using Backbone/Marionette and triggering a "file:added" event for each onSubmit callback. This is where I am creating the modal view and displaying it, however, the solution doesn't need to be tied to backbone.

Also, if there is a better way to collect parameters for a file using fine-uploader, I am not necessarily tied to this approach - just need to make sure that each file has the additional data populated otherwise it can not be uploaded.

Here is the Fine Uploader onSubmit callback:

```
.on('submit', function(event, id, name) {
   var args = {};
   args.id = id;
   args.fileName = name;
   uploadDocsVent.trigger('file:added', args);  
})
```

Here is my code that is listening for that event, creating a File Backbone model, and instantiating a view to be displayed in a Modal region.

```
uploadDocsVent.on("file:added", function(args){
    var file = new UploadDocuments.File( args );    
    var addlInfoView = new UploadDocuments.Views.FileInfo({ 
        model: file, 
        categories: App.uploadedFilesCategories 
    });
    App.appLayout.modalConfirmRegion.show(addlInfoView);
});
```

In my view I have this code responding to the modal clicks:

```
onDialogPrimaryClicked: function () {
    UploadDocuments.claimsUploadWidget.addFileWithInfo( this.model );
    this.trigger("dialog:close");
},

onDialogSecondaryClicked: function () {
    UploadDocuments.uploadView.uploader.fineUploader('cancel', this.model.get('id'));
    this.trigger("dialog:close");
}
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas on how to approach/get around this.

Comment: I answered a somewhat similar question very recently for a user who wanted to place text fields next to each submitted file.  Perhaps this approach would be better?  Let me know if this helps you at all.  If not, please let me know and we'll go from there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026176/add-field-for-each-file-in-fine-uploader

Comment: Thank you Ray. I will definitely take a look and see if that approach would work within our design. P.S. Thank you for your work on the plugin, it's truly excellent!

Comment: I gave this a try and I don't think that this will work out in our case. We have to present 2 select inputs and a text input for each file and the UI is starting to look really busy, especially when taking into consideration the other ui elements already present in framework, file name, action links, messages, etc. I think my options at this point are figure out a way to defer the modals or maybe just turn off multiple. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew - I think I know what you are getting at.  It's clear that you simply want Fine Uploader to only process a file in a batch of selected files after the user has submitted information in the modal that your display for that file in your onSubmit handler.  What you are looking for is a way to return a promise, or a "deferred" in your onSubmit handler.  This would allow you to call Fine Uploader back (and say "go ahead, upload/submit this file and move on to the next") once your user has submitted the associated modal.

I have already created a [`qq.Promise`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/promise.html) "class" that implements the [promise pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/11/asynchronous-programming-in-javascript-with-promises.aspx).  Fine Uploader observes a promise as a valid return value only for the `onPasteReceived` callback at this time.  It might make sense to allow this as a valid return value for other callbacks, such as `onSubmit`.  This would allow you to defer uploading/submittal of a file until the user has dealt with the associated modal.  Setting the `multiple` option to "false" may or may not be a desirable option for you now, due to the way Fine Uploader functions in "single-file mode".

I think it may be valuable to allow promises to be returned in some callbacks, such as this one, to allow for user interaction.  Could you please [open up a feature request](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/new) in the Github project?  There, we can discuss a bit more and you can track progress on any associated changes I put into the library.

Comment: I have gone ahead and opened up the following feature request on GitHub. [link] (https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/805)